# sigaction handle signal just once

Tags: c, signals, sigaction

Is there a way to catch a signal just once with `sigaction` structure and function? To be more specific, I would like to simply reset to default a specific signal (`SIGINT`). Is it possible to achieve this in a handler?

### Edit

So, something like this would be correct:

> ```
> void sig_int(int sig)
> {
>     printf(" -> Ctrl-C\n");
>     struct sigaction act;
>     act.sa_handler = SIG_DFL;
>
>     if(sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL) < 0)
>     {
>         exit(-1);
>     }
>
> }
>
> int main()
> {
>     struct sigaction act;
>     act.sa_handler = sig_int;
>
>     if(sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL) < 0)
>     {
>         exit(-1);
>     }
>
>     while(1)
>     {
>         sleep(1);
>     }
>
>     return 0;   
> }
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The standard SA_RESETHAND flag](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html), set in the `sa_flags` member of `struct sigaction`, does precisely this.

Set that flag when specifying your SIGINT handler, and the handler will be reset to SIG_DFL upon entry.

Comment: I don't know why, but I don't have an access to the SA_* flags, though I included the signal header.

Comment: @Papipone, are you on Linux?  You may need to [define a feature macro](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) like  `_POSIX_C_SOURCE`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can call `sigaction` inside a signal handler. That's specified by Posix, which (in [XBD chapter 2.4.3](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03_03)) "defines a set of functions that shall be async-signal-safe." It then notes that "applications can call them, without restriction, from signal-catching functions. ". `sigaction()` is in that list.

Answer (score 1):

Just restore the default action in program.

```
struct sigaction old;
void sig_int(int sig)
{
        printf(" -> Ctrl-C\n");

        if(sigaction(SIGINT, &old, NULL) < 0)
        {
                exit(-1);
        }

}

int main()
{
        struct sigaction act;
        act.sa_handler = sig_int;

        if(sigaction(SIGINT, &act, &old) < 0)
        {
                exit(-1);
        }

        while(1)
        {
                sleep(1);
        }

        return 0;
}
```